# Center cover image to match with background

Tags: html, css

I have a background picture with size: cover, I also have a part of this image cut out, made lighter and positioned on top of other divs.

The structure is the following
(grey - background, purple - part of this background cut out and positioned on top, pink - menu which is partly(!) covered by that image so I can interact with it) [image]
 The problem is that I want cover image to always match with its background when resizing browser window

I set up top and left manually to match background but it still doesn't when height/width ratio changes

```
    <section class="main">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="content">
            Main page content
        </div>
    <side-container></side-container>
    </div>
    <img class="cover-image" src="../../assets/img/img-shoes@2x.png" alt="sneakers">
</section>
```

SASS:

```
.main
    background-color: black
    background-image: url('../../assets/img/bg.png') 
    background-size: cover
    background-repeat: no-repeat
    overflow: hidden
.cover-image 
    position: absolute
    z-index: 30
    width: 31vw
    height: auto
    left: 4.5vw
    top: 15vh
    bottom: 0
    right: 0
    margin: auto
```

Comment: not any demo link?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure the problem out due to lack of a demo link or an online version to see what's happening.

but I think this is going to work for you:

```
.cover-image 
    position: absolute
    z-index: 30
    width: 31vw
    height: auto
    top: 50%
    left: 50%
    transform: translate( -50%, -50% )
    margin: auto
```

It uses `transform` to change the position of that `<img>` according to its width and height, not parent's.